# Focus and close application by ID

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

In Windows if I have the PID for an application and I want to either focus or close the app via the command prompt.

What commands do I need to run?

e.g.

`FOCUS 123`

or

`CLOSE 123`

Where 123 is the PID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To kill an app instance using its PID, use `taskkill /pid <pid>` (`tasklist` will list all the running processes).

To switch focus to an app instance using its PID, use the VBScript below:

```
set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.AppActivate WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
objShell.SendKeys "% x"
```

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx) says that `%` represents `ALT`. Together with `SPACE` we can access the `Alt-Space` popup menu, and use an keyboard accelerator to maximize or restore the window.

If you save it as *Focus.vbs*, you can invoke it from the command line using:

```
wscript Focus.vbs <pid>
```

Comment: Actually there is a nasty bug with this. If the window is minimized then it makes it impossible to focus any other window as it tries to focus the window but can't and just flickers. Is it possible to get it to focus windows that have been minimized?

Comment: Minimized windows can actually receive focus while remaining minimized. If you want the minimized window to be un-minimized/restored along with receiving focus, let me know and I'll see what can be done about it.

Comment: Yes, I'd like it to un-minimized/restored and then focused so that this bug can't happen. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, give me some time please. BTW, on my system the minimized window's taskbar button lights up showing it has received focus, but there's no flicker and I can easily click on and switch focus to other windows. Not sure what's causing the problem on your system.

Comment: I think it;s the loop that causes it, because it hasn't managed to focus the application properly and thereforce causes it to keep trying and therefore prevents other windows from being interacted with. I've disabled the loop, so it's just a case of doing a restore and a focus and should be fine.

Comment: Yes, most likely the loop's causing the issue. Try the simplified script and see if it works for you. You can replace the `x` in the last line with `r` if you want to restore instead of maximize.

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I kill a process using it's PID?

You can a process using `tskill`:

```
tskill 123
```

**Syntax**

> TSKILL processid | processname [ /SERVER:servername] [ /ID:sessionid | /A] [ /V]

Source [tskill](http://ss64.com/nt/tskill.html)

---

#### How do I set focus to a process using it's PID?

To set the focus to an application you will need to use a 3rd party application, such as [Nircmd Win](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/win.html).

```
nircmd win focus process /123
```

**Syntax**

> nircmd win [action] [find] [window to find] [Additional Parameters]

Source [Nircmd Win](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/win.html)

Comment: I get the error that `win` is not recognised as an internal or external command.

Comment: Can I focus an app without an external program? Thanks

Comment: You may be able to do something with `powershell`.

Comment: `win` is actually `nircmd`'s subcommand, that is full syntax is `nircmd win focus process /123`.

Answer (score 3):

From windows command taskkill:

```
taskkill [/s Computer] [/u Domain\User [/p Password]]] [/fi FilterName] [/pid ProcessID]|[/im ImageName] [/f][/t]
```

Example:
    taskkill /pid 123

Source [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx)